# open link in new tab for the imagebutton in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to get the open link in new tab for the image button in the asp.net please give me the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect using an anchor tag and an image

```
<a href="somepage" target="_blank">
    <img src="yourimagepath" alt="imagetext" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no specification in the W3C for opening a page in a new tab. There is one for opening in a new window, with the attribute

```
target="_blank"
```

You should stick with that because it's really up to the end user to decide how the web browser should behave. In Internet Explorer, for example, there's the option to either open new windows in tabs or window's. Don't try to force the behavior of the browser to do something other than what the user has decided.